# Is it possible to reflect over the details of csproj assembly references?

Tags: c#, reflection, reference, assemblies

We frequently run into trouble because project/package references in our solution are misconfigured (e. g. improperly requiring a specific version). I'd like to write a simple NUnit test to check for these kinds of cases so we can catch them early. Ideally, I'd use reflection over the assemblies rather than parsing the csproj file myself. Is this possible? Can all information from a csproj file be obtained via reflection on the compiled assembly?

Comment: You can't get that information from the compiled output assembly, but you can walk the project files using the `Microsoft.Build` namespaces...will you have access to the csproj files?

Comment: Some details stored in the .csproj file is lost when compiling, but you should be able to get all referenced assemblies and their versions. Would that be sufficient ?

Comment: Expanding on @JerKimball's comment, take a look at the [`Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the reference of a particular assembly by calling `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies`, which will return the AssemblyName's that are referenced. This includes both name and version.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fileName);
var references = a.GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

Comment: Derp - of course: @ChaseMedallion if all you are after is the referenced assemblies, this should do it for you.

Comment: Suppose the `.csproj` file contains references that are not actually used. Like if it refers `System.Data` assembly, but nothing (no class, struct, interface, enum, or delegate type) from that assembly is actually used. Will `GetReferencedAssemblies()` return `System.Data` assembly in that case?

Comment: But will the version be the version of the actual assembly that got loaded or the version specified by the reference? What if the reference specifies no version?